# use of xml files inside WEB-INF under Web Pages folder

Tags: java, jsp

In doing JAVA based web projects using JSP in netbeans, under **Web Pages** folder **WEB-INF** folder is created.
Inside this folder there are 3 *xml pages* viz. **sun-web.xml, web.xml & weblogic.xml**.
When I clicked the web.xml page, it shows different tabs like,

1. general
2. servlets
3. filters
4. pages
5. references
6. security
7. XML

what are the uses of these, how can I configure these settings for my web pages?

eg. *in XML tab, we can set the sesion-timeout value. what can be the other uses of this web.xml and other settings??*

Please explain the use of other two xml files, sun-web.xml & weblogic.xml.

Comment: here http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html you have an overview of different configuration possibilities for your web-application through web.xml, the other file are some proprietary config files (maybe not portable across servlet containers) witch you can ignore at start. Every servlet container, including the one you are using, has to understand web.xml .

Comment: Glassfish server is the default server with Netbean and you have installed Weblogic Server.So, there may be such files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the `sun-web.xml` file is for glassfish server.This file for specifying additional web app (WAR) configuration in Glassfish server.Now-a-days `sun-web.xml` file is known as `glassfish-web.xml`. [Get More](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1750/beaql/index.html)

And about the `weblogic.xml` file is the deployment descriptor for Weblogic Server.If your Web application does not contain a weblogic.xml deployment descriptor, WebLogic Server automatically selects the default values of the deployment descriptor elements. Get more on [Weblogic.xml](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15051_01/wls/docs103/webapp/weblogic_xml.html)

Answer (score 0):

The XML tab gives you direct access to the xml code. the other tabs give you a nice user interface, to edit the xml code.